# assign to another object with retain and autorelease

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, retain, autorelease

I have the following code, expecting that once obj2 is released obj1 is still retained, will it work?

```
obj1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
obj2 = [[obj1 retain] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have the following code, expecting that once obj2 is released obj1 is still retained, will it work?

`obj1` and `obj2` are both pointers to *the same object*. That object gets a retain count of 1 when you create it. The object's retain count increases to 2 when you retain it again on the second line. The object (and any pointers to it) will therefore remain valid until it's released twice. One of those releases will eventually come from the `autorelease` on the second line; another should be supplied by your code somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

It'll work, but I'm not sure your conclusion is correct (had a parse error on that).

```
obj1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];
obj2 = [[obj1 retain] autorelease];
```

It helps to think of retain and release in terms of delta and per-reference.   So, in the following code, you would say that "the obj1 reference has a retain count of +1" and "the obj2 references has a retain count of +0".

That is, `obj1` is a strong reference and `obj2` is a weak reference.

If you want the object to go away, you would `[obj1 release]`.  You *could* `[obj2 release]`, but that implies an ownership transfer which should be made only for good reason and quite explicitly.

Or you could just turn on ARC and be done with it.